# Avoiding wasted CPU cycles while waiting for input

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, interrupt, keyboard-events

My program is waiting for the <kbd>F4</kbd> hotkey to be pressed in order to exit.

I am calling `Sleep(1)` because without this, I am using 18% of my CPU. Is this the correct way to do this? My gut is telling me there is a better way.

I know that keyboard inputs are interrupt-based, but is there any way to make a thread sleep until a keyboard state change is registered?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    while (!(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F4) >> 15)) {
        Sleep(1);  // Sleep for 1 ms to avoid wasting CPU
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to go into the conrtol panel and disable the "energy saving" features?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/samples-notificationicon

Comment: Oh, I see. This has nothing to do with pressing a key every 10 minutes. It's related to listening to a hotkey in order to end the program. Please try to provide a [mre], i.e. a short program that reproduces the problem by removing everything that is not needed. Here, pressing a key every 10 minutes is not needed, the thread is not needed, the message box is not needed, etc.

Comment: why not wait for a keypress event

Comment: if you're not sleep or blocked then it'll use 100% of a CPU. You see 18% because you have a multicore CPU

Comment: @cainsr2 Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [RegisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey), [UnRegisterHotkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unregisterhotkey), [GetMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage), [TranslateMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-translatemessage) and [DispatchMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dispatchmessage) like

```cpp
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{

    RegisterHotKey(0, 1, MOD_NOREPEAT, VK_F4);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) != 0)      // TODO: error handling
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_HOTKEY)
        {
            if (msg.wParam == 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    UnregisterHotKey(0, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

`GetMessage()` will block until it receives a window message, which wakes it up. Get a copy of [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), look into the process details and see it not using a single CPU cycle while it's waiting.